# background color of JPG using wand (Python)

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I use wand with Python to change the background color of a JPEG.

```py
with Image(file=myJpg) as image:
    image.background_color = Color("#f0f0f0")
    image.save(filename='myJpg.jpg')
```

It seems to work because when I resize and extent image the background is filled with "#f0f0f0" (rgb(240,240,240)).

The image is a JPEG.

If I reload the image and get the background, it is white rgb(255,255,255):

```py
with Image(file=myJpg) as img:
    assert img.background_color == Color("#f0f0f0")
```

The assertion is false. I don't understand why?

Comment: The concept of "background color" in a JPG eludes me. A JPG has a single plane/layer and no transparency, and no way to tell which pixels are part of the "background".

Comment: Hi i use Image.extent (https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.extent) in this case it fill empty part with the bacground color. Sorry I'm not expert in image. So, if i understand after i save image the background color become a part of background and we can't defined the color

Comment: Your *"background colour"* is only held within a `wand` variable - it doesn't get written to disk with your JPEG image.

Comment: backgroundcolor is a setting. It does nothting until it is used by an operator such as -extent or -rotate. To change a background color in the image, you would have to do something like `-fuzz XX% -fill "new_color" -opaque "old_color"` (in command line)